# Pop up with javascript

Tags: javascript, button, popup

I am very new to java script, can anyone tell me how I can get a pop up with javascript on a button click.

I need to add some text and image to this popup.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>If you want a new window to open as a popup, you can use:</strike>

```
window.open('newpage.html');
```

This will open the file `newpage.html` in a new window, that you can style however you like with HTML and CSS.

Edit:

If you want to do it inside the same window, I would recommend hiding a div and then showing it on click, like this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ksFhc/1/)

You can use jQuery plugins to achieve this and much more for you, but as a learning exercise the above is very simple and doesn't require external libraries

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
alert('your text');
```

But if you need to customize the popup with images, backgrounds etc then you'd better get your hand on jQuery and study it.

http://jquery.com/

There are many tutorials around, just google for them (or buy a good manual :)

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but in the question it is stated that the OP wants to add images, so `alert()` would never work. Secondly just linking to jQuery.com and saying there are many tutorials around is _not_ an answer! Thirdly offering a jQuery solution to someone who is new to JavaScript might be more confusing that a _simple_ JavaScript solution.

Comment: Ok thanks, I still need to get into these mechanics. I'm ok with a downvote as long as it's explained.

Comment: Actually, looking at the votes, you have `+1` on this and no actual downvotes registered. Maybe they changed their mind?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is to use the jQuery UI popup plugin. You will also need to include the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) library.

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="dialog-message" title="Download complete">
  <p>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
    Your files have downloaded successfully into the My Downloads folder.
  </p>
  <p>
    Currently using <b>36% of your storage space</b>.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using `jQuery Dialog` and this is a sample: [jQuery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated)